# Question Mark (?) symbol in URLs

Tags: url

Recently I have noticed a question mark symbol in my sites slugs.

```
http://www.url.co.uk/?/contact/
```

Does any one no what this means and why it has suddenly appeared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from having Admin > Output and Debugging > Force Query strings to 'yes'.

You may need that for it to work, and you can add it after 'index.php' in your .htaccess file and turn off the EE option to force it into the URL.